# Exporting a Google Map made from Google Maps API for printing

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, printing

I have a map made using the Google Maps API, and I'm looking for a way to export this or something so that I'll be able to print it on a large poster. The map is [here](http://plumassierratelecommunications.com/pstbroadband.php). Are there any existing tools to do this? I hope I'm not coming off as though I'm looking for someone to write my code, I just want a pointer in the right direction. Also, what would the name of this type of map be called? I'm not even sure how to look this issue up. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the ToS let you print out their Maps (I'm 99% sure that they won't let you). If they do, you might want to take a look at the [Google Static Maps API V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/intro). They do allow you to [draw polyline and polygonal](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/intro#PathPoints). However they only let you take 640x640 unless you have a map for work licence.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the likely Terms of Service violation, the simplest solution would be to take a screen shot.